# Is there a way to optimise the time taken for uploading multipart data in a django + react app?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I have an app that has a django rest framework backend and a react frontend. As usual the user has an option to edit the details he has initially submitted. The details also contain a profile picture of the user. The update view works fine, but what I have noticed in the network tab is, if the user tries to update his profile it takes upt 5-8s and sometimes 27s for the react frontend to receive a response from backend.

#### Question

Is there any way to reduce this time or any performance optimisation method?

I am also posting my code incase I am doing something wrong.

**react part**

```
export const editTeacherDetail = async (detailsData, photo) => {
  console.log("detailsData before in main api = ", detailsData);
  console.log("photo before in main api = ", photo);

  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("name", detailsData.name.toUpperCase());
  formData.append("state", detailsData.state);
  formData.append("adhaar_number", detailsData.adhaar_number);
  formData.append("current_profession", detailsData.current_profession);
  formData.append("phone", detailsData.phone);
  formData.append("location", detailsData.location.toUpperCase());
  formData.append("full_address", detailsData.full_address.toUpperCase());
  formData.append("date_of_birth", detailsData.date_of_birth);
  formData.append("gender", detailsData.gender.toUpperCase());
  formData.append("name_of_school", detailsData.name_of_school.toUpperCase());
  formData.append("experience", detailsData.experience);
  formData.append("teach_for_no_days", detailsData.teach_for_no_days);
  formData.append("subject", detailsData.subject.toUpperCase());
  formData.append("teach_class", detailsData.teach_class);
  formData.append("home_tuition", detailsData.home_tuition);
  formData.append("fees", detailsData.fees);
  formData.append("home_tuition_fees", detailsData.home_tuition_fees);
  formData.append("shift", detailsData.shift.toUpperCase());
  formData.append("board", detailsData.board.toUpperCase());

  if (typeof photo !== "string") {
    formData.append("profile_photo", photo);
  }

  try {
    console.log("formData = ", formData);

    let response = await axiosInstance.put(`/teacher/edit-detail/`, formData);
    console.log(response);
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      ToastNotification(
        "We are facing some problems. Please try again later",
        "error"
      );
      return error.response;
    } else if (error.request) {
      console.error(error.request);
      return error.request;
    } else {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
};
```

**django part**

```
@api_view(['PUT'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
@parser_classes([MultiPartParser, FormParser])     
def edit_teacher_detail(request):
  
   data = request.data
   
   if data is not None:
     
     queryset = TeacherDetail.objects.get(user = request.user)
     
     serializer = TeacherDetailUpdateSerializer(instance=queryset, data = data)
     
     try:
       if serializer.is_valid():
         serializer.save()
         return Response({'message':"details edited"} ,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
       else:
         print(serializer._errors)
         return Response({'message': serializer._errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
     except Exception as e:
       print(e)
       return Response({"message": str(e)},status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
     
     
   
   else: 
      return Response({'message':'no query recieved'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**profile model**

```
def profile_upload_to(instance,filename):
    id = instance.id
    user = instance.user.id
    return f'teacher-profile-picture/{filename}'.format(filename=filename)

class TeacherDetail(models.Model):
    
    STATE_CHOICES = (
        ("AN", "Andaman and Nicobar"),
        ("AP", "Andhra Pradesh"),
        ...
    )
    
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    
    profile_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = profile_upload_to, null=True, blank=True)
    
    adhaar_number = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    
    current_profession = models.CharField(max_length= 20, null=True, blank=True)
    
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=STATE_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    
    full_address = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    
    date_of_birth = models.DateField( null=True, blank=True)
    
    name_of_school = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    
    experience = models.IntegerField( null=True, blank=True)
    
    teach_for_no_days = models.IntegerField( null=True, blank=True)
    
    shift = models.CharField(max_length=20 ,null=True, blank=True)
    
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    
    teach_class = models.CharField(max_length=100 ,null=True, blank=True)
    
    board = models.CharField(max_length=25,null=True, blank=True)
    
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=8 ,null=True, blank=True)
    
    fees = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    
    fac = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    
    home_tuition = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    home_tuition_fees = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    
    hfac = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    
    home_tuition_students = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, blank=True, related_name='home_tuition_students')
    
    general_tuition_students = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, blank=True, related_name='general_tuition_students')
    
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable= False)
```

**serialiser used in the update view**

```
class GetTeacherInfoEditSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = TeacherDetail
    exclude = ['id','date_created','user','home_tuition_students','general_tuition_students']
```

Comment: Could you please post the model and serializer, too?

Comment: @SörenWeber yes sure, I have updated my question. Please have a look

Comment: In theory, if you use PUT you will update all the data in the model (including profile image), you can try using PATCH and avoid sending the picture if doesn't change in the front end.

Comment: @educolo Patch with ```partial=True``` ?

Comment: @RitankarBhattacharjee yes.
     serializer = TeacherDetailUpdateSerializer(instance=queryset, data = data, partial=True)